# Angular6: get only Distinct subscription

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a `BehaviourSubject<Object> selectedObject` which emits the value `this.selectedObject.next(newObject)` 
and this next is triggered only once. However, I have a subscription 
 `this.selectedservice.selectedObject.subscribe((emittedObject: Object) => { doWork();}` which is being called more than one time.

Note: this duplication emit is not a constant value and this is happening at an incremental number during one of my functional flow scenario. Not sure why there are duplicate subscriptions happening for a single .next()

I am looking for a solution where for a .next() I should execute the dowork() only once for distinct. `First(), Take(1), Last()` with the pipe will not work out for me since there will be multiple emits and I need to capture it.

The below implementation with distinctUntilChanged() is not working

```
this.selectedservice.selectedObject..pipe(
                distinctUntilChanged()).subscribe((emittedObject: Object) => { doWork();}
```

Can someone advise?

Comment: a behavior subject emits once upon subscription and then at every next call.  if you don't want this behavior, you may want a different kind of subject

Answer (score 0):

When you use `distinctUntilChanged()`, it will do a simple comparison and not check the fields equality.

If you want to disctinct according to all the fields of the object, then you need to pass the comparison function in `distinctUntilChanged`:

```
distinctUntilChanged(myComparisonFunction),
```

If you want the comparison on only ONE field, then you can use:

```
distinctUntilKeyChanged('myKey')
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your code which subscribes to `selectedObject` is being run multiple times.

A BehaviorSubject always has a value that gets sent to subscribers immediately upon subscription.

I recommend instead, in your constructor, you create a shared observable that only subscribes once to the underlying observable when something else subscribes to it. It unsubscribes from the source observable when the last thing unsubscribes from it.

```js
this.selectedObject$ = this.selectedservice.selectedObject.pipe(share());
```

(The `name$` syntax is a common convention for Observable variables/properties)

Then just use `this.selectedObject$.subscribe(() => doWork());`.

Note that if these subscriptions are made in a sequence after `doWork()` completes, then it will still call `doWork()` each time. It depends on how the multiple subscription calls are being made.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the responses, distinctUtilChanged() was not working for my scenario despite comparison with the keys. I was able to solve the issue by having a Subscriptions array and add all my subscriptions into it. This was avoiding the duplicate call.

```
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs';

//Inside your component class declare 
public subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];

//push the subscription 

this.subscriptions.push(this.selectedservice.selectedObject.subscribe((emittedObject: Object) => { doWork();});
```

post this, the dowork() is not being triggered multiple times.